# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django

Tags: python, django

I get this **Error** when I do a get request and not during post requests.

> Error:-
>
> ### MultiValueDictKeyError at /StartPage/
>
> ```
> "Key 'username' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
> ```
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>
> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/StartPage/
> ```
>
> Django Version:   1.4 Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError Exception
>   Value:
>
> "Key 'username' not found in "

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.template import Context, RequestContext
@csrf_exempt
def main_page(request):
    return render_to_response('main_page.html')

@csrf_exempt
def Start_Page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       print 'post', request.POST['username']
    else:
       print 'get', request.GET['username']
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'username':request.POST['username'],
           'password':request.POST['password']})
    return render_to_response('Start_Page.html',variables)
```

**urls.py**

```
from polls.views import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^$', main_page),
     url(r'^StartPage/$', Start_Page)
```

**main_page.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is the body
<form method="post" action="/StartPage/">{% csrf_token %}
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Sign with password">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Start_Page.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is the StartPage
Entered user name ==   {{username}}
Entered password  == {{password}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you are not passing `username` as a `GET` parameter while getting the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/StartPage/` page.

Try this and observe username printed: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/StartPage?username=test`.

Use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and avoid `MultiValueDictKeyError` errors:

```
request.GET.get('username', '')
```

See also:

- [Django request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500859/django-request-get)
- [Django - taking values from POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the request you are getting doesn't contains **disabled**. If the field which you are getting contains **disabled**. It will give this error.
So, in order to solve this make sure your don't have a ***disabled*** word in your field.
e.g

```
 <input  name="numberid" disabled class="form-control"  value="{{p.id}}" type="text"></div>
```

In my case, the ***disabled*** keyword was causing this error.