# Access form data of post method in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to access post method data in views.py. I am following procedure of using pure html for form not **Django form class**. I tried the solution 
[MultiValueDictKeyError in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531030/multivaluedictkeyerror-in-django?noredirect=1&lq=1) but still it is not working. Help me out

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url "Sample:print" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter anything" id="TB_sample"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def print(request):
    value=request.POST['TB_sample']
    # value = request.REQUEST.get(request,'TB_sample')
    # value = request.POST.get('TB_sample','')
    print(value)
    return render(request , 'static/Sample/print.html',{"data":"I want to pass here 'Value'"})
```

I tried all commented types. still i get the many errors . None of these solutions working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rename the print name of your function ( you called def print ). Never name a function of python builtin functions.

First, you have to give a name to input field to get the post parameter. Like,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter anything" name="TB_sample" id="TB_sample"/>
```

Then , you have typed

`value=request.POST['TB_sample']`

in django function.Which throws the **MultiValueDictKeyError** if there are no parameter named TB_sample.Always write,

`value=request.POST.get('TB_sample')`

which outputs None instead of throwing errors.

Comment: when i use value=request.POST.get('TB_sample') it raise **'str' object has no attribute 'POST'**

Comment: for value=request.POST['TB_sample'] it raise **MultiValueDictKeyError** after i tried ur solution

Comment: Man! you give your function name print !! Rename this print function to something else.Also see the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give *'name'* to the input:
`<input name="firstname" type="text" value="firstname">`

In django (*views.py*)

```
def register_form(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        name = request.POST['firstname']
        print(name)

    return redirect('/')
```