# Django optional parameter is not readed from url

Tags: python, django

I was reading the thread [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)
And following the steps to generate a URL with a single optional parameter.

Well, my URL should be:

```
/client/
/client/?clientname=John
```

And I have defined two urlpatterns

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^/(?P<clientname>\d+)/',views.index),
```

Well, at this point both of them render the page.
But, in my view:

```
def index(request, clientname='noparameter'):
    print("The searched name is: " + str(clientname))
```

The searched name is always `noparameter`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you are getting confused between a keyword argument and a get request. Using keyword arguments, which your `urls.py` is configured for, your view would like this:

```
def index(request, **kwargs):
    clientname = kwargs.get("clientname", "noparameter")
    print("The searched name is: " + str(clientname))
```

Your urls.py would also have to change to this for the url to this:

```
url(r'^client/(?P<clientname>\w+)/',views.index),
```

This could be called in the browser like:

```
/client/John
```

Comment: You right! After read the thead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500859/django-request-get#3500932 I have more clear what you write me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Url you are having is

```
/client/John/
```

instead of

```
/client/?clientname=John
```

also even in the following example using John will fail as your regex is for digits , check out more on topic of [django dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example)

```
  /client/4/
```

if you want to get GET parameters instead you can do that in view by using the following

```
request.GET.get('clientanme', None)
```